# What happens in iOS 13.0 and prior if I only ask for approximate location?

Tags: ios, location

I'm fairly new to the iOS mobile development ecosystem.

Since precise/approximate location permission specificity was only introduced in iOS 14.0, I was wondering what would happen to my mobile application running on an older iOS version 13.0 if I only requested approximate location?

- **Answer A)** On iOS 13.0 and prior, I would get back precise location only - regardless of whether or not I requested permissions for it.
- **Answer B)** On iOS 13.0 and prior, I would get back approximate location or precise location - depending on which permission I requested.

**Which is the correct answer? I was unable to find official Apple documentation for this detail.**

[image: iOS Location Permission Prompt]

Comment: Did you actually try it? If you don't have a real iOS 13 device, you can try out Xcode Simulator.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Experimental simulator results aren't always reliable, right? As mentioned in my post, I was unable to find official Apple documentation for this detail. If you were only able to catch male Tuna fish in the ocean, it would be incorrect to assume all Tuna fish were male!